# Is it possible to run embedded AND client server derby database at the same time?

Tags: java, database, derby

Background:
I am about to enhance an existing application. This application uses already derby.

For an other use case I want to use derby, too.

Is it possible to run embedded AND client server derby database at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. We call this "Embedded Server", and you can find more details here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/adminguide/cadminov17524.html

Answer (score 0):

Not it is not possible to run the derby in both the modes at the same time. But if you run derby in the network or client/server mode then both your local and remote applications can access the databse. Remote applications means, applications running in different JVMs on the same machine or on remote machines.

Comment: That is incorrect. You can start the database in embedded mode and then start a network server as Bryan Pendleton has stated in his answer.