# Multiple access to a single derby database

Tags: java, database, derby, multi-user

I have created a simple java desktop application using derby database, I have used embedded driver to connect the database.

The problem is derby database can't access by multiple time using embedded database.

If more than one client application tries to access the database, shared lock occurs.

How can I make the database access by the multi user at the same time?

What driver I want to use for that?

Comment: See this configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17053074/193453

Answer (score 5):

Embedded Derby cannot be booted (opened) by multiple JVMs, though multiple accesses from the JVM which booted the database are allowed. If you want to access the same Derby database from multiple applications (JVMs), you should use [Derby Network Server](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible for desktop application??

Comment: Derby Network Server is client-server model; thus by its nature, it have to be separated from the desktop application. What is your application's requirement?

Comment: My application is a java desktop application, I have used derby for a simple search application. Is there any other database in java for multi user access.

Comment: What is the _multi user access_? Multiple users accessing the same application, or Multiple users using multiple applications on the same machine? Your requirement seems too vague to answer correctly.

Comment: Multiple users accessing the same application

Comment: How do they access the same desktop application? Via network? If the only one desktop application exists and multiple users access the application somehow, you can control multiple accesses by concurrent utilities or raw threads.

Comment: In case anyone else tries this, I was **unable to connect to the same embedded database from different clients** within the same VM.